# Generate covariance matrices in batch (TensorFlow)

Tags: tensorflow

I wonder how to generate covariance matrices in batch in TensorFlow. If we use the following code

```py
dim = 3
df = 5
ds = tf.contrib.distributions
scale_sqrt = tf.random_normal([dim, dim], seed=1234)
scale = tf.matmul(scale_sqrt, tf.transpose(scale_sqrt))
sigma = ds.WishartCholesky(df=df, scale=scale).sample()
```

it would work. But if we try the batch version of this code by adding an additional batch dimension then TF would throw an error. My batch version looks as follows:

```py
dim = 3
df = 5
ds = tf.contrib.distributions
num_per_batch = 10
scale_sqrt = tf.random_normal([num_per_batch, dim, dim], seed=1234)
scale = tf.matmul(scale_sqrt, tf.transpose(scale_sqrt, [0,2,1]))
sigma = ds.WishartCholesky(df=df, scale=scale).sample()
```

Please let me know how to sample in batch efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

For posteriority, this bug has been fixed, and should be available in the tf-nightly versions (when I call sess.run(...) on sigma, I get back values with no errors).